# Dynamic Filtering of the Array based on the multiple words entered in the Search bar using with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've implemented a code which will filter the Array of items using the Keywords in the Search tab.

As we enter/delete the keywords entered in the Search tab the Array gets filtered in real time and displayed on the screen.

"Person" Array needs to be filtered:

```
var person = [{fname : "John1", lName: "ABC", age: 46},
{fname : "John2", lName: "ABC", age: 55},
{fname : "John3", lName: "XYZ", age: 96}];
```

"Search Array" :

values entered for in searchArray = `John ABC 55;`

"OUTPUT" :

```
[{fname : "John2", lName: "ABC", age: 55}]
```

Comment: [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: So what happens if the user enters `hn AB 5`? In other words, what are the rules around the searching? Starts with? Contains? Exact match? How about `96 XYZ John3`? I.e., does the order matter? Etc.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - partial matching is also allowed.

Comment: @AndrewPaul - if we add "John" -> all 3 rows filtered, After "John ABC" entered -> first 2 rows got filtered , "John ABC 55" -> will filter out 2nd row

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all requirements. It's not fair to keep those requirements to yourself, answer the question, then divulge what the code was supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: @heretic Monkey..as mentioned in the question as well, search can happen with multiple keywords. As we enter/delete the search keyword, the displayed array gets filtered out

Comment: @Heretic Monkey - For eg - on facebook Search, we search with multiple keywords like name ,place and the results gets filtered out in real time.... I hope this explains the my requirements

Comment: Again, you've explained it well... in the comments. Just not in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
    searchArrayList = searchArray.split(' ');

    filteredArray = person.filter(function (item) {
                                let row = [item.fname != null ? item.fname.toLowerCase() : '',
                                    item.lName != null ? item.lName.toLowerCase() : '',
                                    item.age != null ? item.age.toLowerCase() : ''].join();
            
                                let result = searchArrayList.map(function (part) {
                                    if (part === '') return true
                                    return row.indexOf(part.toLowerCase()) !== -1
                                })
                                
                                return result.reduce(function (x, y) {
                                    return x&y
                                }, true)
                            })
```

**EXPLAINATION:**

1. Split the searchArray string "John ABC 55" into Array `['John', 'ABC', '55']`

   ```
   searchArrayList = searchArray.split(' ');
   ```
2. `JOIN()` method will cause the Person array item into single string : `[{"John2", "ABC", 55}] => "John1 ABC 55"`
3. Map the search result into boolean Array :

   ```
   ["John1 ABC 55"].indexOf("John") => 'true',
   ["John1 ABC 55"].indexOf("ABC") => 'true',
   ["John1 ABC 55"].indexOf("55") => 'true'
   ```

   Map result => [true, true, true]
4. Reduce will result into single boolean array : `true`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming query's format won't change, this is how I'd do it:

```
function filterPerson(arr, query) {
   let [fname, lName, age] = query.split(" ").filter(function(chunk) {
      return chunk.trim().length > 0;
   };
   age = age ? +age : null; //converts age to number

   if(!fname) return [];

   arr = arr.filter(function(person) {
      return person.fname.startsWith(fname);
   });

   if(!lName) return arr;

   arr = arr.filter(function(person) {
      return person.lName.startsWith(lName);
   });

   if(!age) return arr;

   arr = arr.filter(function(person) {
      return person.age === age;
   });

   return arr;
}
```

It would be possible to do it in a single filter function, but then you'd have to check whether first name, last name, and age is set every time you'd filter the array. This way you check the query only once and filter an already filtered query.

Alternatively, you could create a filtering function for each use case e.g. when there is one parameter, two, three, or more parameters.

Or you could reorder the filtering sequence to remove as many entries as possible as early as possible.

Good luck!